# LOAD csv file with specified column values

Tags: database, db2

I have 2 csv files that contains 4 cols(c1,c2,c3,c4) and created a table that contain 5 columns (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5).
Now I want to load those two files into the tables separately such that for each time I can have a contant value that goes in a1 column of the table.

Values in csv file 1

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
............
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Values in csv file 2

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
............
5 6 7 8 
5 6 7 8 
5 6 7 8 
5 6 7 8
```

resulting table should be

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 ,a5
..................
my_value1 1 2 3 4
my_value1 1 2 3 4
my_value1 1 2 3 4
my_value1 1 2 3 4
my_value2 5 6 7 8 
my_value2 5 6 7 8 
my_value2 5 6 7 8 
my_value2 5 6 7 8
```

I tried this but clearly doesn't work and I read the load documentation from the IBM site but I wasn't able to find anything.

```
load from path\file1 of del insert into table_name(my_value1, c1,c2,c3,c4)
load from path\file2 of del insert into table_name(my_value2, c1,c2,c3,c4)
```

Comment: You have tagged this as JDBC-related, but there is no JDBC (or Java) usage in the question.  You should remove the `jdbc` tag from your question, if it is not relevant.

Comment: If you actually _are_ using Java/JDBC then you can also use a CSV library (e.g. [openCSV](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or similar) to read the source files, and prepare the data - and then (as a separate step) load that consolidated data to the DB using JDBC. There are many Java/CSV and JDBC questions already on SO for you to use as a reference.

Comment: Look at the [Moving data using a customized application (user exit)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-moving-using-customized-application-user-exit) article, if you really need LOAD. If not, then look at the [INGEST command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got some good suggestions in the comments, so this is just another way to do it:

```
db2 "create table target(a1 varchar(20) not null, a2 int, a3 int, a4 int, a5 int)"
db2 "alter table target alter column a1 set default 'my_value1'"
db2 "load from ./f1.csv of del insert into target (a2,a3,a4,a5)"
db2 "alter table target alter column a1 set default 'my_value2'"
db2 "load from ./f2.csv of del insert into target (a2,a3,a4,a5)"
db2 "alter table target alter column a1 drop default"
db2 "select * from target"

A1                   A2          A3          A4          A5         
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
my_value1                      1           2           3           4
my_value1                      1           2           3           4
my_value1                      1           2           3           4
my_value1                      1           2           3           4
my_value2                      5           6           7           8
my_value2                      5           6           7           8
my_value2                      5           6           7           8
my_value2                      5           6           7           8

  8 record(s) selected.
```

You may also have a look at [INGEST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest)

```
-- create restart table
CALL SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS('INGEST', 'C', NULL, NULL);

INGEST FROM FILE f1.csv      
    FORMAT DELIMITED (        
        $a2  INT EXTERNAL,
        $a3  INT EXTERNAL,
        $a4  INT EXTERNAL,
        $a5  INT EXTERNAL
    )     
    INSERT INTO target (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
    VALUES ('my_value1',$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5);
```

From my understanding it is almost as fast as load, but much more flexible. There is a comparision at:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ibm-db2-111/9781788626910/15f1d83a-dc08-432c-b91b-f48fba48756d.xhtml

Finally, there is a new kid in town named [EXTERNAL TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-external-table). You have to enable a path for EXTBL_LOCATION in your db cfg. I.e:

```
db2 update db cfg using EXTBL_LOCATION /tmp
```

Then you can declare a curor:

```
db2 "declare c1 cursor for select 'myval1', a2, a3, a4, a5 from external '/tmp/f1.csv' (a2 int, a3 int, a4 int, a5 int) using (delimiter '|')"
```

For reasons unknown to me I could not get it to work with ',' as delimiter so I changed it in the file.

Now, you can load from that cursor:

```
db2 "load from c1 of cursor insert into target"
```

Redefine the cursor and load another file (I used the same one)

```
db2 "declare c1 cursor for select 'myval2', a2, a3, a4, a5 from external '/tmp/f1.csv' (a2 int, a3 int, a4 int, a5 int) using (delimiter '|')"
db2 "load from c1 of cursor insert into target"

 db2 "select * from target"

A1                                       A2          A3          A4          A5         
---------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
myval1                                             1           2           3           4
myval1                                             1           2           3           4
myval1                                             1           2           3           4
myval1                                             1           2           3           4
myval2                                             1           2           3           4
myval2                                             1           2           3           4
myval2                                             1           2           3           4
myval2                                             1           2           3           4

  8 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: This way of doing I tried already, and it works fine, but I need to know if there is any way we can insert a specified constant value in a column while loading the data file.  Appreciate the help though.

Comment: Added some info about INGEST

Comment: @HiteshwarSingh, I added some info on external table and load from cursor